# .htaccess force ssl execlude some url(s)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect every request to "https" instead of any call to "example.org/forum/...", but hunderets of solutions did not work and I can't figure out why for example this approach does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: I've tried this example now on a domain with just some folders, index.html files and a .htacess file with nothing but these two rules in the root and works like charm!

The point is that I try to achieve this on a domain with a cms underneath, it is a contao installation and there it does not work. I also tried it on a wordpress installation and there it does not work too!
So I think it has something to do with internal redirections, does anyone has a clue!? I can't find such a case on the web...

Comment: you want all requests go to https, except the `/forum`, go to http?

Comment: exactly! and all urls "under" /forum/... i.e. /forum/threadXY, or /forum/?newthread and so on should be http too, any request without "/forum/" should be https...

Answer (score 2):

The [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) `REQUEST_URI` is starting with `/`, you should make these rules change:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oh, you're right, but I've tried this syntax too and it did not work either... It seems like the problem is something else, I've changed my questions, maybe you have also a clue for that case!? :)

Comment: did you set `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`?

Answer (score -1):

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomaim.com$

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ folder name [L]

It works for me redirect all to https

Foldername is the folder after youdomain.com/foldername

Comment: But I don't want to redirect all, "/forum/..." should be excluded!

Comment: @ToTaTaRi if you don’t want all exclude the last rewrite rule